# Issue with archive: DerivedData/ProjectName-fjzvotpzpzoiltaayiafiugoaany/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/La: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, targets

I've problems when archiving my apps. I have various targets and each one of them is connected with an app of the Store.

I need to submit these targets on the store but when archiving them 4 targets are not able to work properly, while the other 7 don’t produce any error.

I think there is a problem with derived data.

I already deintegrate pods and reinstall, deleted derived data folder and cleaned the project but nothing looks like properly working.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the provisioning. It seems everything are fine until the code signing step.

Comment: @t4nhpt What should I check in provisioning?

Comment: The build works correctly, the error affects only the archiving.

Comment: Each target has a separate provisioning. Double check if you use right bundle id. Then delete the provisioning for that bundle and download again.

Comment: I use right bundle id and delete the provisioning and download again hs no effect.
Now error is: ........./Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-fjzvotpzpzoiltaayiafiugoaany/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/KeyARt: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable